# Better autocompletion in sublime for SCSS

Tags: autocomplete, sass, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In sublime, if I type "border" and then TAB, it guesses: "border-top-left-radius" which annoys me like hell. I have to set the syntax to "LESS" to get a better autocomplete.

Why is sublime acting this way? Is there a plugin to get a better autocompletion for SCSS files?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is old I am having the same issue. When I am typing `db` i get `box-decoration-break:` and seriously who cares about this property I just want to get `display:block`.  Or when I type `dib` I am hoping to get `display:inline-block;`

What I did is to install `emmet` using the `Package Manager` and then on User Preferences (Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Settings - User ) disable autocomplete: `"auto_complete": true`

Now with Sass my files are looking good and the autocomplete feature works well, you can also use `emmet` with `hayaku`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package named [SCSS](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SCSS) In sublime's [package-control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) plugin.

> A Sass & SCSS syntax package for Sublime Text 2

(note: it's working for me with sublime-text-3 as well)

It's lets you choose 'SCSS' syntax, and performs just as it should.

Give it a try.

There are installation notes on the package web-site,
You can install it manually, or through package-control.

If you havn't installed package-control yet, I recommend that you do.

It's one of sublime's best features in my opinion, you can find many packages to improve your productivity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Same issue here.. If I type border then TAB, I get border-top. This is just an example. It does the same with other css properties. I just want a clever autocomplete. the LESS one is pretty good. I just don't want to have to set it for every file I open.

Comment: 'bd' gives me 'box-decoration-break' for some reasons.. Anyway I just found Hayaku which does a pretty good job.